# Solving $ y^{\prime\prime}=\tan(y)+\tan(y)^3 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
y^{\prime\prime}=\tan(y)+\tan(y)^3
$$
I don't understand how to solve this kind of equations, all I know are the methods of solving common DE. But for this type I have no idea how to start!
I thought that I could use $U=\tan(y)$ , but in the end I got more stuck.

What I really want to understand is how to think when I get similar equations?

Comment: Use $$\frac{1}{2} (y'^{2})' = y'y'' = y'(\tan(y) + \tan^{3}(y)) = y'(\tan(y) \sec^{2}(y)) = \frac{1}{2} (\tan^{2}(y))'$$ then integrate.

Comment: so we multiply by $y'$ , but how to find the idea itself ? I mean according to what ?

Comment: It's a pretty standard technique when you have an ODE whose order is separated by $2$. For example, try it on $y'' + y = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

This equation does not explicitly depend on $x$. Therefore you can try substitution of the form: $y'(x)=p(y(x))$, where $p$ is some function of $y$. In this case $y''(x)=p'(y(x))p(y(x))$. Prove it! Then your equation reduces to $p'(y)p(y)=\tan(y)+\tan(y)^3$.Now you can find $p$. If you do it right, then you should arrive at $p(y)^2=\tan^2(y)+C$

Comment: isn't $y"(x)$=$y'(x)$$p'(y(x)) $?

Comment: Recall the definition of $p$

Comment: oh right ! p is y' itself !